# Come si dice "What brings you to [place]" in italiano?

Tags: translation, phrase-request

Ho incontrato per caso un gruppo di ragazze italiane sull'autobus. So che loro non sono di queste parti ed io vorrei chiedere loro cosa fanno a Montreal.

Cerco un modo alternativo e più colloquiale per chiederlo di:

> Cosa fate a Montreal?

In inglese direi:

> What brings you to Montreal?

Comment: Perché "cosa *fanno* a Montreal?"?

Comment: @writingthesis È meglio dire `Cosa fate a Montreal`?

Comment: Sì. Hai due casi:
1. Vuoi essere informale: se fosse una ragazza, "Cosa fai", 2a pers. sing.. Più di una, "Cosa fate?", 2a pers. pl. 
2. Vuoi essere formale: se fosse una ragazza, "Cosa fa", 3a pers. sing.. Più di una, "Cosa fate?", 2a pers. pl. La 3a pers. pl. non si usa (almeno, non si usa più) per rivolgersi in modo formale a un gruppo di persone.

Comment: The verb is absolutely correct, just the person was wrong. What is your mother language?

Comment: Sono di madrelingua francese. Conosco bene la differenza tra le forme familiare e di cortesia. L'uso di `fanno` era una svista :-)

Comment: E io che avevo apprezzato il ricercato “fanno” per rivolgersi a più persone sconosciute! Qualche persona anziana che sull'autobus chiede “Scendono?” capita ancora, ogni tanto.

Comment: @DaG Solitamente sono prudente coll'uso della forma familiare, però credo che queste ragazze siano più giovani di me allora mi sembra appropriato.

Comment: Certo, fenceop, all'atto pratico sarebbe una ricercatezza forse eccessiva.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Espressioni colloquiali che potresti usare sono:

- Siete in vacanza qui a Montreal?
- Cosa fate di bello qui a Montreal?
- Come mai da queste parti?

oppure:

- Cosa vi porta a Montreal? as you suggest in English.